# Email client to answer multiple emails with same reply

Tags: email, email-client

I am looking for any free or paid email client that could achieve this simple task :

1) Select messages in my Inbox based on a text search with basic operators: e.g. "German AND iOS"

2) Reply (preferrably one reply per message, as I believe it is less likely to trigger gmail's antispam) to all the senders of these messages with the same text: e.g. "Hi, German language is supported in the iOS version since yesterday!"

I have already tried the following options which don't seem to offer this feature:

- Gmail's webmail
- Thunderbird
- Postbox
- Outlook 2013